# Create Procedure Liquibase

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I try to create a procedure to postgresql with liquidbase when i start up the application.

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
```

The procedure (function in real) i try to integrate is like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema_for_materialized_views.update_views() RETURNS VOID AS
$$
BEGIN

  refresh materialized view schema_for_materialized_views.first_view WITH no data;
  refresh materialized view schema_for_materialized_views.second_view WITH no data;
  refresh materialized view schema_for_materialized_views.first_view;
  refresh materialized view schema_for_materialized_views.second_view;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I tried to put this into an  tag, into a  with reference to an external file, and into a  with the inside containing this.
I have no other idea how else to write it to make it work.
So if someone has a suggestion .. .

EDIT: the 4 main changeSet-s i tried so far:

```
<changeSet  author="TS"  id="add_function">
    <createProcedure
            replaceIfExists="true"
            dbms="postgresql"
            schemaName="schema_for_materialized_views"
            path="db/changelog/update_results.sql"
            procedureName="update_views">
    </createProcedure>
</changeSet>
```

```
<changeSet  author="TS"  id="add_function">
    <sql dbms="postgresql">
      CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema_for_materialized_views.update_views() RETURNS VOID AS
    $$
    BEGIN

      refresh materialized view schema_for_materialized_views.first_view WITH no data;
      refresh materialized view schema_for_materialized_views.second_view WITH no data;
      refresh materialized view schema_for_materialized_views.first_view;
      refresh materialized view schema_for_materialized_views.second_view;

    END;
    $$
       LANGUAGE plpgsql;
   </sql>
</changeSet>
```

```
<changeSet  author="TS"  id="add_function">
    <createProcedure
            replaceIfExists="true"
            dbms="postgresql"
            schemaName="schema_for_materialized_views"
            procedureName="update_views">
      refresh materialized view schema_for_materialized_views.first_view WITH no data;
      refresh materialized view schema_for_materialized_views.second_view WITH no data;
      refresh materialized view schema_for_materialized_views.first_view;
      refresh materialized view schema_for_materialized_views.second_view;
   </createProcedure>
</changeSet>
```

```
<changeSet  author="TS"  id="add_function">
    <createProcedure
            replaceIfExists="true"
            dbms="postgresql"
            schemaName="schema_for_materialized_views"
            procedureName="update_views">
      CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema_for_materialized_views.update_views() RETURNS VOID AS
    $$
    BEGIN

      refresh materialized view schema_for_materialized_views.first_view WITH no data;
      refresh materialized view schema_for_materialized_views.second_view WITH no data;
      refresh materialized view schema_for_materialized_views.first_view;
      refresh materialized view schema_for_materialized_views.second_view;

    END;
    $$
       LANGUAGE plpgsql;
   </createProcedure>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `changeSet` you are using.

Comment: added the ways i tried so far, (of course each time i tried to run from the same state, so i can know that this is not a conflict of that type)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it with some IRL help:

```
            replaceIfExists="true"  
            dbms="postgresql"
```

can not work together.