# How do you create a function in Liquibase + Postgres with a SQL file and JSON config?

Tags: postgresql, function, liquibase

Related, didn't fix:

[Liquibase error [Postgresql]: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$BODY$](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734806/liquibase-error-postgresql-unterminated-dollar-quoted-string-at-or-near-bod)

[Create Procedure Liquibase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70272802/create-procedure-liquibase)

https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/create-procedure.html

My config:

```json
{
  "databaseChangeLog": [
    {
      "changeSet": {
        "id": "0002004",
        "author": "jcollum",
        "changes": [
          {
            "description": "add function for getting metadata",
            "tagDatabase": {
              "tag": "v2.0.4"
            },
            "sqlFile": {
              "dbms": "postgresql",
              "path": "../artifacts/000204_metadata_function.sql",
              "relativeToChangelogFile": true,
              "splitStatements": false,
              "stripComments": false,
              "encoding": "utf8",
              "endDelimiter": ";"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and the SQL, trimmed down for space:

```sql
/*
comment here edited for clarity 
*/

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_metadata;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_metadata(account_id varchar)
RETURNS TABLE(
    country varchar,
    "state" varchar,
    county varchar,
    )
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
'
    /*
    calculates metadata about an account:
    input:
    ...
    */
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT ...
    GROUP BY c.id ...
'
END;
$$;
```

Also tried  `"endDelimiter": "$end$"` with

```sql
END;
$$;
$end$
```

Also tried without the `' [function text] '` block, same result, a syntax error (I think syntax error for `$$` in that case).

Everytime I run this I get some variation on `Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "'` or `Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near $$`

My process, up to this point, has been to get the sql script running fine in a SQL editor then deploy it with Liquibase. For some reason doing this with a function is breaking Liquibase and I don't see why. The function creates just fine outside of Liquibase and the function works as intended. I would very much prefer to keep this as a sql file because the rest of the project is set up that way.

What's wrong with this configuration? I've been messing with this for an hour at least and I'm very frustrated with Liquibase being so finicky.

Apologies for the vertical space but I need it to be complete, so it's gonna be large and even then it's not actually complete. **SO really needs collapsible code blocks.**